# jQuery - data() == 'something' always return false

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a function depending on value of data attribute.
But it always return `false` when I run this:

```
alert(jQuery(this).data('loaded') == 'no');
```

But my data attribute was set to no, and when I alert

```
alert(jQuery(this).data('loaded'));
```

it return the correct data attribute value.

**Update**

HTML

```
<a class="btn" href="#" data-loaded="no"></a>
```

**All of code**

```
jQuery('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (jQuery(this).data('loaded') == 'no'){
        ajax();
        jQuery(this).attr('data-loaded', 'yes');    
    }
});
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like (or the relevant code where you set the attribute)?

Comment: `$('<a class="btn" href="#" data-loaded="no">').data('loaded') == 'no'` returns `true` for me. What is `this` in your context?

Comment: added my jquery function too

Comment: probably this is happening due to this ???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g6tvx/1/ seems to suggest this works fine...

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Actually I was using `this` outside function

Comment: Set the attribute when `ajax` call finishes. here you are immediately setting it after call to `ajax();` but `ajax` will be finishing lateer.

Comment: If your question is now resolved, please consider adding some text at the top of your question indicating that, or add your own answer.

Comment: Please do not add `[solved]` to the title. If you have an answer, write your own below and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to do it onclick event but your anchor doesn't have anything. so change you markup and try

```
<a class="btn" href="#" data-loaded="no">Click Here</a>
```

of-course you can achieve this with some styling like border or padding. All you make your anchor clickable.

```
a
{
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq2pA/)

Comment: It could have a border and padding, which makes it clickable without text.

Comment: @Blender yes you are write, It can be achieve by that as well. Here I am just telling him the cause and let him know to use click event.Thanks

Comment: thanks for answer, answer is not related to me, but will help future users. I am giving +1

Comment: @user1983017 please let me know, why it is not useful for you? what else you want?